# How to select anchor tag using Xpath for selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, webautomation

I am using Selenium for web automation but can't able to select the anchor tags which has onClick attribute with no href and class Names. Below is the source code of form where i want to click on first and third anchor tags

```
<td colspan="4" class="leftTopFormLabel">
    12. Details of Nominee :<span class="mandatoryField">*</span>
</td>
<td colspan="2" class="lastFormValue">
    <a onclick="openWin('NomineeDetails.aspx','','dialogWidth:1000px; dialogHeight:800px; center:yes')"
        style="text-decoration: Dynamic; color: Blue; cursor: pointer">Enter Details Here</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="lastData_Section" id="Tr12">
<td colspan="4" class="leftTopFormLabel">
    13. Family Particulars of Insured Person:
</td>
<td colspan="2" class="lastFormValue">
    <a onclick="openWin('FamilyDetails_New.aspx','','dialogWidth:1000px; dialogHeight:800px; center:yes');"
        target="_blank" style="text-decoration: Dynamic; color: Blue; cursor: pointer">Enter
        Details Here</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="lastData_Section" id="Tr18">
<td colspan="4" class="leftTopFormLabel">
    14. Details of Bank Accounts of Insured Person:<span class="mandatoryField">*</span>
</td>
<td colspan="2" class="lastFormValue">
    <a onclick="openWin('EmployeeBankDetails.aspx','','dialogWidth:1000px; dialogHeight:800px; center:yes');"
        style="text-decoration: Dynamic; color: Blue; cursor: pointer">Enter Details Here</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

Can anyone suggest me ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Using the contains method to parse the onclick attribute:

```
//a[contains(@onclick,'NomineeDetails.aspx')]
```

Answer (score 0):

None of your `<a>...</a>` elements have an `href` attribute. None of them have a `class` attribute.

Here's one way to select those with an `onclick` attribute but without a `target` attribute.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''\
<td colspan="4" class="leftTopFormLabel">
    12. Details of Nominee :<span class="mandatoryField">*</span>
</td>
<td colspan="2" class="lastFormValue">
    <a onclick="openWin('NomineeDetails.aspx','','dialogWidth:1000px; dialogHeight:800px; center:yes')"
        style="text-decoration: Dynamic; color: Blue; cursor: pointer">Enter Details Here</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="lastData_Section" id="Tr12">
<td colspan="4" class="leftTopFormLabel">
    13. Family Particulars of Insured Person:
</td>
<td colspan="2" class="lastFormValue">
    <a onclick="openWin('FamilyDetails_New.aspx','','dialogWidth:1000px; dialogHeight:800px; center:yes');"
        target="_blank" style="text-decoration: Dynamic; color: Blue; cursor: pointer">Enter
        Details Here</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="lastData_Section" id="Tr18">
<td colspan="4" class="leftTopFormLabel">
    14. Details of Bank Accounts of Insured Person:<span class="mandatoryField">*</span>
</td>
<td colspan="2" class="lastFormValue">
    <a onclick="openWin('EmployeeBankDetails.aspx','','dialogWidth:1000px; dialogHeight:800px; center:yes');"
        style="text-decoration: Dynamic; color: Blue; cursor: pointer">Enter Details Here</a>
</td>
</tr>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

matches = soup.select("a[onclick]:not([target])")
for a in matches:
    print(a.attrs.keys(), a.text)
```